# Ionic 2: Authenticating through Instagram with Firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to authenticate Instagram with a Firebase integration, following the JS example [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/10/authenticate-your-firebase-users-with.html).

I have set up Firebase in `app.component.ts` using

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

which has seemingly worked.

On `home.html` I simply have a login button:

```
<button ion-button (click)="connect()">Login</button>
```

Which calls this on `home.ts`.

```
connect(){
    console.log("Connecting")
    window.open('http://localhost:8080/redirect', 'firebaseAuth', 'height=315,width=400');
}
```

Now is where I'm a little confused. The log in is successful, and the pop-up Instagram closes as should happen with the *node* server shown in Firebase's example.

I then have, in the constructor, for change detection:

```
  this.zone.run(() => {
    this.checkAuth()
  });
```

With this.checkAuth():

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
          // User is signed in.
          console.log('Connect:', user);
        } else {
          // No user is signed in.
          console.log('No connect:');
        }
      });
```

Nothing appears in console after window close. However I'm pretty sure I'm missing something.
Any help greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: AFAIK this implementation is specifically for the browser and may not work when running on a mobile device. You may need to install the relevant Cordova plugin.  I recently did auth using [AngularFire2 for Ionic](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/Auth-with-Ionic2.md) and it was pretty straight-forward.

Comment: @Und3rTow Thanks for the info. I'm actually only trying in browser for now, and will use InAppBrowser flow on device. But it shouldn't be a problem here, as I'm not running in cordova. Does Af2 have a similar .onAuthStateChanged? Because Insta's not a default Firebase authentication, so needs a node backend like above.